# css word wrapping issue with margin left set

Tags: css

I have a script that produces rows of data from a MySQL table. If the text (data) is longer than the space available, the text wraps. Thats fine, but when the text is wrapped the margin on the wrapped line is ignored.

The code:

```
<div class="TabelText"><?php echo $row_Audits['SeqText'];?></div>

.TabelText {
   font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #950000;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The result:

```
   0401 Bathroom Door & Frame (Inside 
and Outside)
```

Is there a way to produce a result like:

```
0401 Bathroom Door & Frame (Inside 
and Outside)
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: can you provide a live example

Comment: @Gerardo BLANCO Hi, I don't think that's possible because the data comes from my server and I don't want to display any of the connections.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this display: inline-block;

```
.TabelText {
   font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
   font-size: 12px;
   color: #950000;
   margin-left: 10px;
   display: inline-block
 }
```